# How adding Kotlin coroutine name in logging?

Tags: kotlin, logging, logback, kotlin-coroutines

Working with coroutines, it is possible to use the `-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug` jvm option to display the coroutine names in the log as explained in the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#debugging-using-logging).

How is it possible to reproduce that effect without the jvm option but with a configuration of the logger (logback for example) and/or the application.properties file?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to get the coroutine name, but it is possible to use the MDCContext module to add a MDC value to the coroutine that can be logged using the %X{} of logback.